# how to sort the field in the mongo document which is inside array

Tags: spring, mongodb, sorting

I have below a structured Mongo Document:

```
{
  "_id": value,
  "imageShared": {
    "imageid": value,
    "commentdatadoc": [
      {
        "whocommented": value,
        "commenttext": value,
        "commenttimestamp": isodate(111)
      },
      {
        "whocommented": value,
        "commenttext": value,
        "commenttimestamp": isodate(444)
      },
      {
        "whocommented": value,
        "commenttext": value,
        "commenttimestamp": isodate(222)
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Here I want to sort the field `commenttimestamp` desc. I tried the way below but it is not working...

```
Query getComments = new Query();
getComments.addCriteria(Criteria.where("imageShared.imageId").is(imageId)).
    with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC,"imageShared.commentDataDoc"));
    SharedMediaCollec sharedMediaCollec = mongoTemplate.findOne(getComments, SharedMediaCollec.class);
```

Does anyone have an idea how to sort a document field which is inside array?

Comment: You are trying to sort one element: `mongoTemplate.findOne` will always return one element. The sort is applied to a set of result, you are telling mongoTemplate to sort the returned `SharedMediaCollec`s by `imageShared.commentDataDoc`, not to sort its `commentDataDoc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to get all documents anyway, it might be far easier to do the sorting in C# after you received the data from MongoDB. An elegant way to do this automatically would be to represent the `commentdatadoc` array in your C# object with a [SortedSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

But when you definitely want a database-sided solution, you can do it with an [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) consisting of a $match-step, a $unwind step and a $sort step. To perform an aggregation with the C# driver, call [`collection.Aggregate`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_Aggregate__1.htm) and then set the aggregation stages at [the returned `IAggregateFluent` interface](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IAggregateFluent_1.htm).

Comment: Thanks i did used Aggregation. and FYI i am doing in Java with Spring MVC.

Comment: @SriniReddyM : could you please provide your solution here? i'm having the same requirement but didn't able to make it work yet.